# Cases when savedInstanceState is NOT null

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-bundle, android-savedstate

If I do not explicitly call `onSaveInstanceState()`, which are possibilities, when `savedInstanceState` is not null in `onCreate`?

I see one option, when system recreates my app after crash - then `savedInstanceState` is not null.

Which are other options?

Comment: We do not call `onSaveInstanceState()` ever. It's a lifecycle callback and so Android calls it itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which are possibilities, when **savedInstanceState** is not **null** in **onCreate()**?

1. System was on shortage of memory, so it killed the process of your app. User navigates to your app, now `onCreate()` will be called with non-null `Bundle`.
2. After configuration change (e.g. orientation change) - `onCreate()` will be called with non-null `Bundle`.

> If I do not explicitly call onSaveInstanceState()

You shouldn't do that on your own. It's the system that will call activity lifecycle methods and `onSavedInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: When I run app from Android Studio, if same activity is re-created on startup, then onSavedInstanceState() is also non-null.  This happens even with instant run disabled.  It's really annoying how onDestroy works differently when developing

Comment: @LouMorda do you mean "savedInstanceState" paramter of the `onCreate()` instead, because a method being null/non-null makes no sense.

Comment: @Sufian, did I mention *"null/non-null method"* in the answer?

Comment: @azizbekian I was responding to LouMorda's comment, hence it started with "@LouMorda".